# How to enforce minimal height in pdfmarkupcomment?

Tags: highlighting, pdfcomment

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{aa}{Highlight}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{AA}{Highlight}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{gg}{Highlight}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{Ag}{Highlight}
\end{document}
```

The different highlighted markups have different heights. Normally, many pdf reader produce for all three types the latter height.

Can I enforce the usage of a *minimal* height of the latter sort?

(It should still properly increase height for other non-standard letters like umlauts, e.g. `Ä`.)

I tried the `height` option. But this seems not to have an effect on the markup.

ps. You might need to compile a couple of times to see the highlight properly (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330276/36836).

Comment: You can add a \strut: `\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{\strut aa}{Highlight}`

Comment: Your comment was faster than my answer! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can patch `\pdfmarkupcomment` so that every appearance of `#2` becomes `\strut#2`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\pdfmarkupcomment}
 {#2}
 {\strut#2}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{aa}{Highlight}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{AA}{Highlight}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{gg}{Highlight}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{Ag}{Highlight}
\end{document}
```

but beware that this will apply `\strut` everywhere, not only when some markup comments are near to each other.

Alternative patching:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\originalpdfmarkupcomment\pdfmarkupcomment
\renewcommand{\pdfmarkupcomment}[3][]{%
  \originalpdfmarkupcomment[#1]{\strut#2}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{aa}{Highlight}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{AA}{Highlight}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{gg}{Highlight}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{Ag}{Highlight}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might use the height of capital letters and the depth of y, but beware that capital letters usually overshoot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\originalpdfmarkupcomment\pdfmarkupcomment
\renewcommand{\pdfmarkupcomment}[3][]{%
  \originalpdfmarkupcomment[#1]{%
    \hbox{\vrule height \fontcharht\font`A depth \fontchardp\font`y width 0pt}%
    #2%
  }{#3}%
}

\begin{document}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{aa}{Highlight}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{AA}{Highlight}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{gg}{Highlight}
  \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{Ag}{Highlight}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can fix the overshoot by using `` 1.1\fontcharht\font`A `` and the result would be

[image]

and you may want to do similarly for the depth.

Comment: Thanks. The `\strut` seems to be slightly larger than the extremes letters `A` and `g`. Do you happen to know the `\rule` that would make it exactly the height of the letters?

Comment: @Daniel You can use ``\vrule height \fontcharht`A\font depth \fontchardp`y\font width 0pt`` instead of `\strut`

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct command? I just get a bunch of errors... Sorry, I was a bit too quick with accepting the answer. The height does not yet match the desired from the question.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I always put `\font` in the wrong position.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `\strut` to get the height of a base line. Or define your own `\boxheight` as in the example. You must define it in a macro without argument, otherwise it will not survive the SOUL parser used by `pdfcomment`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\newcommand\pdfstrutmc[3][\strut ]%
{%
  \pdfmarkupcomment{#1#2}{#3}%
}%
\newcommand\boxheight{\raisebox{-3pt}{\rule{0pt}{15pt}}}
%
\begin{document}
  \pdfstrutmc{aa}{Highlight}
  \pdfstrutmc{AA}{Highlight}
  \pdfstrutmc{gg}{Highlight}
  \pdfstrutmc{Ag}{Highlight}

  \bigskip
  \pdfstrutmc[\boxheight]{Aa}{Highlight}
  \pdfstrutmc[\boxheight]{AA}{Highlight}
  \pdfstrutmc[\boxheight]{gg}{Highlight}
  \pdfstrutmc[\boxheight]{Ag}{Highlight}
\end{document}
```

[image: pdfcomment minimal box height]